# using User.set_password method in my model in django

Tags: django, django-authentication

Is it possible to use `set_password` method of `User` model for other models? In general if I want to hash a password can I use any methods of auth package or I should write my own method? (I'm using Django 1.4, Python 2.7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password
```